# Understanding the behaviour of $F(x)=e^{(1/(x-b)-(1/(x-a))}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the function $F(x)=e^{(1/(x-b)-(1/(x-a))}$ over the open subset $(a,b)$ of $R^{1} $and Zero otherwise ( we let $0<a<b$ ). Is this function differentiable over $R^{1}$? A two-sided limit doesn't exist at $a$ and $b$ but in page 3 in   [Helgason's Differential geometry , Symmetric spaces and lie groups](http://books.google.com.eg/books?id=wd-sXTUGk98C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false)  he says that it's differentiable on $R^{1}$ in fact infinitely differentiable.

Comment: You have it backwards: it should be $e^{1/(x-b)-1/(x-a)}$, which does approach $0$ as $x\to a^+$ and as $x\to b^-$. In each case the exponent $\to-\infty$.

Comment: Does a two-sided limit exist at $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Sure: the limits from outside the interval are clearly both $0$, since the function is constantly $0$ out there.

Comment: I don’t use W|A, so I’m not familiar with just what can be done; can you specify the full, piecewise definition of $F$? Because if you gave it only the exponential, it would assume that the exponential applied outside $[a,b]$ as well as inside.

Comment: See also [bump function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function).